# Error in quantile.default(resid) : missing values and NaN's not allowed

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to predict the time it takes for a model to train (sklearn's linear regression) given a particular number of rows and columns. I have created additional features like by taking the log and squares of number of rows and columns.

I have pasted the data [here](https://pastebin.com/eT8ebhjK).  As you can see, the dataset has no missing values or NaN's.

I tried to run a linear regression model in R using the `lm` function using the below code -

```
library(data.table)
df = fread(linreg_df_edited.csv)
lrmodel <- lm(time ~ rows + columns + volume + rows_log + columns_log + volume_log + row_sq + col_sq, data = df)
```

But when I request the summary of the model using `summary(lrmodel)`, I get the following error

```
Error in quantile.default(resid) : 
  missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
```

My dataset doesn't have any missing values but I still tried and rebuilt the model after setting `na.action=na.omit`

```
lrmodel <- lm(time ~ rows + columns + volume + rows_log + columns_log + volume_log + row_sq + col_sq, df, na.action=na.omit)
```

I still get the same error. I can't figure this out. I thought maybe the a column is being read as a character variable. But that too isn't the case.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I was getting the same error. While summary(x) showed no missing data, for some reason a few integer columns are getting autotransformed into integer64 format. Saving as as.numeric(x) solved my problem. Some have mentioned this problem with large datasets, which mine is

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to model on all of your transformations at once.  Your call is:

```
model <- lm(time ~ rows + columns + volume + rows_log + columns_log + volume_log + row_sq + col_sq, data = df)
```

Instead, do:

```
model_lin <- lm(time ~ rows + columns + volume, data = df)
model_log <- lm(time ~ rows_log + columns_log + volume_log, data = df)
model_sq <- lm(time ~ row_sq + col_sq, data = df)
```

Then you'll see the squares are the problem. They're generating the `NaN` values.

Comment: Got the issue. R for some reason is reading the data incorrectly for `row_sq`. Do you also get entries of the order of `10^-15` in the `row_sq' column after reading in the data?  I scaled the `row_sq'  data by dividing by 1000 and re-ran the model. It works now.

Comment: @ClockSlave Oh good! Glad you were able to find the problem this way!  Yes, and the same scaling works here. Feel free to mark this as the answer if it showed you where your problem was :)

Comment: The explanation you added in the edit is slightly incorrect (maybe). I had to change the data in Excel because r kept reading it wrong. This was probably because the original values were too large. Scaling them down at the source and reading it back tackles the issue. No more errors.

Comment: @ClockSlave That change solved it on my end. Did you try it and it didn't work?

Comment: Nope. The data you have posted here is correct. When I read in the data, I get this-  https://imgur.com/a/m6NzW. See the `row_sq` column. I assumed maybe because the values are too large. So I scaled them down(div by 1000) and read the data again. R reads the data correctly after the scaling operation.

Comment: @ClockSlave You're welcome. if you'd like to write you own answer and accept it, if the answer here isn't satisfactory, then this question won't stay hanging in the "no answer" queue